# Footer code displays red in CSS stylesheet, but HTML code is fine

Tags: html, css, compiler-errors, footer

[image]The errors didn't come up earlier... i just noticed it last night when i tried to save my file. what could be wrong? Cause i have had a look at the HTML code and nothing is seems off.

```css
footer {
  background-color: #023440;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 800px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.logo-footer {
  height: 70px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer-nav {
  list-style: none;
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.social-links {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -40px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.footer-nav li,
.social-links li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.footer-nav li:last-child,
.social-links li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.footer-nav li a:link,
.footer-nav li a:visited,
.social-links li a:link,
.social-links li a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
  color: #a3a3a3;
  font-weight: 400;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

.footer-nav li a:hover,
.footer-nav li a:active {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.social-links li a:link,
.social-links li a:visited {
  font-size: 135%;
}

.footer-address p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 90%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.copyright {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.copyright:before {
  display: block;
  height: 0.1px;
  background-color: #045d71;
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.ion-social-linkedin,
.ion-social-instagram,
.ion-social-twitter {
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

.ion-social-linkedin:hover {
  color: #007bb5;
}

.ion-social-instagram:hover {
  color: #e95950;
}

.ion-social-twitter:hover {
  color: #55acee;
}

.email-footer {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  transition: color 0.3s, border-bottom 0.3s;
}

.email-footer:hover {
  color: #a3a3a3;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #a3a3a3;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span-3-of-3">
      <ul class="footer-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="span-3-of-3">
      <ul class="social-links">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-instagram"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-twitter"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span-3-of-3">
      <img src="resources/img/euphoric%20Logo%20footer-01.png" alt="euphoric-logo-footer" class="logo-footer">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="footer-address">
      <p>40 Alison Road.<br>
        <a class="email-footer" a href="#">info@euphoric.co</a></p>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p class="copyright"> Copyright &copy; 2020, Euphoric. All rights reserved.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

[image]

[image]

The errors didn't come up earlier... i just noticed it last night when i tried to save my file. what could be wrong? Cause i have had a look at the HTML code and nothing is seems off.

Comment: How you mean footer code shows in red? The only reds i see is the classname instances from CSS, which can be any colour depending on your editor theme

Comment: need content... where are you taking those screenshots? what errors? we're only looking at a 'section' of a file but not the whole thing it seems. Do you have an online reference or live copy of your site we can check?

Comment: @Jayr Thanks for the response. I am using Brackets editor, and the classnames usually appear in blue, but red means there's an error. so the error really is that, initially the code would run very well and all items with class names in css, where in place on the browser. But now they're oversize and everywhere, which means they're not responding to the stylesheet code. ----- i have added an updated picture to the earlier questions asked.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code for navigation for example?

Comment: @Capagris, Thanks for the response. I am taking the screenshots from my editor Brackets, i don't see the errors myself, but my editor has marked the CSS classnames red meaning, there's something wrong somewhere. when i launch on my browser my footer is out of place and looses its styling from the stylesheet, nothing is in place anymore, which wasn't happening until, last night after i saved.

Comment: try copy pasting your code to codepen.io and then share with us the link please

Comment: based on that screenshot above, it looks like there is no css for the navigation

Comment: okay @Capagris, that's link on codepen.io: https://codepen.io/Isibert/pen/yLOJrgV

Comment: @Capagris, I don't understand, if you have a look again you at the codepen link, you would see the CSS for the navigation.

Comment: ok, let me look deeper

Comment: check the revised answer - found a major error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open your code in any text/code editor, you can see that there's plenty of errors in there, for example:

```
.pos-info: before {
```

there shouldn't be a space between the : and the before

```
padding: 0 auto;
```

chrome marks this as invalid

```
.img_description:hover {
    transform
    
}
```

property without a value

```
.pos-content: after {
```

again, there shouldn't be a space between : and after

**edit: more errors found:**

On line 921

```
.cloud-content {
```

doesn't have a closing tag, which breaks everything after  it. This is probably the cause of most of your problems.

Comment: Thanks @Capagris. this was the problem. .cloud-content {